# Calling jQuery plugin from document.ready throw getPreventDefault error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application and I have jQuery plugin, calculating width and height of page and I am calling this from document.ready function. I am getting following error

```
ReferenceError: getPreventDefault is not defined MyCustomScript:1:115
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5389:0
no element found
```

### my plugin

```
(function($) {

$.fn.adjustOuterStripLayout = function () {

    alert("strip");

    $(window).bind('load resize', function () {

        var viewport_height = $(window).height();

        var viewport_width = $(window).width();

        var webPage_containerWidth = $('.container').width();

        alert("viewport_width  " + viewport_width + "container " + webPage_containerWidth);

    });
 };
})(jQuery);
```

### main function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  alert("hello");

 $(this).adjustOuterStripLayout();
});
```

sometime it alert and sometime it not. I have also clear browser cashed and testing this on firefox and jquery version 1.10.2

Comment: error shows  getPreventDefault is  deprecated form jquery version you use .. which jquery version you use?

Comment: go to this link http://jquery.com/download/ and download  jQuery Migrate Plugin . then check

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the same in 'window.onload' event instead of in 'documen.ready' ?
As, you are trying to refer the window object to get height & width. Unless its not loaded you wont get that value.

Try using code like:

```
$(window).load(function () {  
 $(this).adjustOuterStripLayout();  
});
```

Comment: i have another application with same version of jquery along with same jquery and call exactly as above I have define but that works fine